# Compressing vectors into cartesian products

Tags: python, algorithm, cartesian-product

I have N 10-dimensional vectors where each element can have value of 0,1 or 2.
For example, `vector v=(0,1,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,1)` is one of the vectors.
Is there an algorithm (preferably in python) that compresses these vectors into a minimum number of Cartesian products. If not perfect solution, is there a algorithm that at least gives a good compression.

Example: the two "Cartesian vectors"
`([1,2], 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, [0,1], 0])` (gives 4 vectors) and `(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, [0,2], 2, 0, 1)` (gives 2 vectors) gives optimal solution for the N=6 vectors:

```
1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0
2,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0
2,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0
0,1,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,1
0,1,0,2,0,0,2,2,0,1
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [`numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html) and [`scipy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/) libraries?

Comment: Perhaps [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) can help you.

Comment: itertools.product seems to creates vectors from stated cartesian products, where I would like to go the other way around. Might be helpful to use in algorithm though.

Comment: How many vectors do you have?

Comment: Differs from time to time, but normaly around 3000

Comment: Can resulting products overlap?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but isn't this trivial? Let your vectors be v_1...v_N and the j coordinate of vector i is v_i^j.  Then define sets S_j = {v_1^j,...v_N^j}.  The min # is S_1xS_2,...S_M where M is the # of dimensions.  This is minimum because if you remove an element from any of the sets, you'd leave out a vector.

Comment: That space (S_1xS_2,...S_M) includes a lot more vectors than I started with. I need combinations of different S_1xS_2...S_M that exactly covers my original vectors

Answer (score 0):

If your vectors were (0,1)-valued, you'd be faced with minimal DNF problem, [which is](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~khot/papers/minDNF.pdf) (correct me if I am wrong) NP-hard. Having (0,1,2)-valued vectors doesn't make a problem any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

A greedy algorithm maybe useful:

```
Let S = <V1, V2, ... Vn>

has_merge_ops = True

while has_merge_ops:
    has_merge_ops = False

    S' = []
    for v in S:
        if there exits v' which differs from v by just only ONE element:
            V = merge v and v' by merging the different values at index k
            S'.append(V)
            S.remove(v)
            S.remove(v')
            has_merge_ops = True

    S = S'

return S
```

So it works like this:

```
after sorting, S = 
0,1,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,1
0,1,0,2,0,0,2,2,0,1
1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0
2,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0
2,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0

After first pass:
0,1,0,2,0,0,[0,2],2,0,1
1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,[0,1],0
2,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,[0,1],0

After 2nd pass:
0,1,0,2,0,0,[0,2],2,0,1
[1,2],0,1,0,0,0,1,1,[0,1],0

Algorithm stops since no more merging is possible.
```

Comment: Thanks zsong! I will try it out. Little worried that If I start with the rows spanned by ([0,1], [0,1], 0) and ([0,2], [0,2], 1), I will end up with ([0,0,[0,1]]), (0,1,0),(0,2,1), (1, [0,1], 0), (2,[0,2],1) as a solution. But might work well with larger starting sets.